# Mongo DB: no result found when using $near query

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, geospatial

I am using Mongo DB to store coordinates and I want to find coordinates using $near query, but I got no result, can anybody help me?
Here is my index of mongo db

```
> db.course.getIndexes()
[
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "_id" : 1
            },
            "name" : "_id_",
            "ns" : "dev.course"
    },
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "coordinate" : "2dsphere"
            },
            "name" : "coordinate_2dsphere",
            "ns" : "dev.course",
            "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 3
    }
]
```

Here is my data

```
{ "_id" : 1,  "schoolId" : 0, "longitude" : 0, "latitude" : 0, "coordinate" : [ 0, 0 ], "courseTitle" : "暂无", "imageIds" : "[]", "videoIds" : "[]", "startTime" : "", "teacherIds" : "[]", "gradeIds" : "[]", "subjectId" : 0, "expense" : 0, "followNum" : 0, "courseStatus" : "NOSTART", "authorizationStatus" : "NO", "rejectReason" : "", "createTime" : "2017-01-01 16:58:22" }
```

My query is

```
db.course.find({"coordinate": {"near": [123, 20]}})
```

There is no result. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`$near`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/near/) is the operator to use, if you write `near` it will only match a field named `near` under `coordinate` field.

The `$near` request would be like :

```
db.course.find({
    "coordinate": {
        "$near": {
            $geometry: {
                type: "Point",
                coordinates: [123, 20]
            }
        }
    }
})
```

To use `2dsphere` index the document should be of [`GeoJSON`](http://GeoJSON) format which needs an additionnal `type` field :

```
{ type: "<GeoJSON type>" , coordinates: <coordinates> }
```

So you just need to replace `"coordinate" : [ 0, 0 ]` with :

```
"coordinate": {
    type: "Point",
    coordinates: [0, 0]
}
```

Comment: It works, thank you so much!!! If I use 2dsphere index the document then I  must use GeoJSON format but if I use 2d index the document then I can use both GesJSON and legacy coordinate pair, is that right?

Comment: Can you tell me what's wrong with this query: > db.course.find({"coordinate": {"$near": [123, 20], "$limit": 100}})

Comment: Yes 2d is for legacy coordinate, 2dspere for GeoJSon format. You can limit the number of result with a `find` with `db.course.find({"coordinate": {"$near": [123, 20]}}).limit(100)`

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. But I still have a question that how can I get the calculated distance and if I want to get the document that the calculated distance is within a given value, how can I do that? I am using 2d to index the document. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `$maxDistance limits the results to those documents that are at most the specified distance from the center point` : is that what you are looking for ? check [$near doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/near/)

Comment: Hi, that is what I am looking for, thank you very much! You helped me a lot!